# Rollup with show_original function using Notion API

Tags: notion-api

I'm trying to retrieve a rollup property value that's of type "select", like so:

```
const rollupName = 'foo';
const prop = await notion.pages.properties.retrieve({
  page_id: page.id,
  property_id: page.properties[rollupName].id,
});
```

`page.properties` contains the rollup property:

```
foo: {
    id: 'Rv%5Cn',
    type: 'rollup',
    rollup: { type: 'array', array: [], function: 'show_original' }
  },
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
{"object":"error","status":400,"code":"validation_error","message":"Invalid relations found in rollup."}
```

How can I get the select value?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely related to permissions for your App / Connection on the related page.

Navigate to the related page, click the 3 dots menu on the top right and ensure your app is listed under Connections.

Not all pages inherit connections if their permissions have been manually updated. Your app has to have permissions to every related page.